# error with custom Mui based input on react hook form

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, material-ui

I tried to make a generic text input component based on Mui Textfield to use in react hook form but i get this error : 
useField must be used inside of a  component 
I used useController like the react hook form documentation suggested it.

My component :

```
import { Grid, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { inputTextStyle, requiredColor } from "components/Inputs/InputText/InputTextStyles";
import { ITextInputProps } from "components/Inputs/TextInput/TextInputInterfaces";
import { TextField } from "mui-rff";
import { useController } from "react-hook-form";

function TextInput({
  label,
  placeholder,
  helperText,
  required,
  mode,
  multiline,
  rows,
  mY,
  name,
  rules,
  control,
}: ITextInputProps) {
  const { field, fieldState } = useController({ name, rules, control });
  return (
    <Grid
      {...field}
      item
      container
      justifyContent="space-between"
      alignItems="center"
      alignContent="center"
      my={mY ?? 0}
      pb={helperText ? 1 : 0}
    >
      <Grid item xs={5}>
        <Typography>
          {label}
          {required && <span style={requiredColor}> *</span>} :
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={7}>
        <TextField
          disabled={mode === "read"}
          name={name}
          placeholder={placeholder ?? label}
          size="small"
          required={required}
          multiline={multiline}
          rows={multiline ? rows : 0}
          sx={inputTextStyle}
          helperText={fieldState.error && rules[name].message}
        />
      </Grid>
      {helperText && (
        <Grid item container justifyContent="end" xs={12} mt={0.5} pr={4}>
          <Typography variant="subtitle2" component="p">
            {helperText}
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
      )}
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default TextInput;
```

Its interface :

```
import { Control, UseControllerProps } from "react-hook-form";

export interface ITextInputProps extends Omit<UseControllerProps, "control"> {
  label: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  required?: boolean;
  mode?: string;
  helperText?: string;
  mY?: number;
  multiline?: boolean;
  rows?: number;
  control: Control<any, any>;
}
```

How I use it :

```
 <TextInput
          control={control}
          mode={mode}
          mY={2}
          label={translate("app.admin.tableHead.lastName")}
          name="surveyCode"
          required
        />
```

How do I resolve the issue ?